# Kmeans clustering on large dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, k-means, bigdata

I have epinions dataset that has 290000 columns and 22166 rows.
Its large dataset and 340 MB , when I open this mat file it take about 30 min to load it on Matlab and when I run my clustering code its impossible to give me any output, all my problem is the big size of dataset, I test it with R programming language and it was same, is there any solution to compress dataset ? What can I do now ? Thanks

Comment: Are the datapoints column- or row vectors? Where does the data come from? You can easily just randomly draw a subset of all the data points and perform k-means on those.

Comment: You can partially load a matfile in Matlab, and work with it just like you would do with a regular loaded variable http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html

Comment: Hmmm? 290000 * 22166 * 8 bytes (for a double) = 51 gigabytes? Am i missing something?

Comment: I cant do the kmeans on subset of dataset, it should perform on all data

Comment: Matthew ,the size of dataset is 440 mb

Comment: I used switch to compress mat file and its 440MB

Comment: If you cannot tell us anything about the structure there is no way to compress the data. I suspect you can highly reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: Maybe the dataset is sparse?

Comment: @ShayanAsadpoor Maybe it's 440mb compressed on disk, but a 290000 by 21666 matrix of doubles would take up 51 gigabytes in memory, way more than most normal computers would have. In addition to O(n) issues, you'll get crushed speedwise by having to use virtual memory.